Why in orders I got error Call to a member function getKeyName() on null?
In  Laravel 10 / nova 4.27 app I have orders model defined as :
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Casts\MoneyCast;
use App\Enums\OrderOtherShippingEnum;
use App\Enums\OrderStatusEnum;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use KirschbaumDevelopment\NovaChartjs\Traits\HasChart;
use KirschbaumDevelopment\NovaChartjs\Contracts\Chartable;

class Order extends Model implements Chartable
{
    use HasChart;

    protected $table = 'orders';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = true;

//    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts
        = [
            'expires_at' => 'date',
            'last_operation_date' => 'date',
            'completed_by_manager_at' => 'datetime',
            'price_summary' => MoneyCast::class,
            'status' => OrderStatusEnum::class,
            'other_shipping' => OrderOtherShippingEnum::class,
            'updated_at' => 'datetime',
            'created_at' => 'datetime',

        ];

    protected $fillable
        = [
            'creator_id', 'postponed_back_order_item_id', 'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_company',
            'billing_phone',
            'billing_email', 'billing_country', 'billing_address', 'billing_address2', 'billing_city', 'billing_state',
            'billing_postcode', 'info', 'price_summary', 'items_quality', 'payment', 'currency', 'status',
            'order_number', 'other_shipping', 'payment_client_ip', 'last_operation_date', 'mode', 'manager_id',
            'completed_by_manager', 'completed_by_manager_at', 'created_at'
        ];

and having resource for it like:
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

...

class Order extends Resource
{
    use ColumnTogglerTrait;
    use HasTabs;

    public static $model = \App\Models\Order::class;

    public static $globalSearchResults = 10;

    public static $showColumnBorders = false;
    public static $perPageOptions = [10, 25, 100];

    public function fieldsForIndex(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
        ];
    }

    public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
        ];
    }


    public function cards(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
        ];
    }

    public function filters(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function lenses(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function actions(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [];
    }
}

I got error :
[2024-11-29 13:43:50] local.ERROR: Call to a member function getKeyName() on null {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function getKeyName() on null at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Fields/ID.php:98)
[stacktrace]
#0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Resource.php(605): Laravel\\Nova\\Fields\\ID::forModel()
#1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Resource.php(469): Laravel\\Nova\\Resource->serializeWithId()
#2 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/digital-creative/column-toggler/src/ColumnTogglerTrait.php(27): Laravel\\Nova\\Resource->serializeForIndex()
#3 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php(60): App\\Nova\\Order->serializeForIndex()
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Support\\HigherOrderCollectionProxy->Illuminate\\Support\\{closure}()
#5 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php(600): array_map()
#6 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php(778): Illuminate\\Support\\Arr::map()
#7 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php(59): Illuminate\\Support\\Collection->map()
#8 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Resources/IndexViewResource.php(23): Illuminate\\Support\\HigherOrderCollectionProxy->__call()
#9 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Resources/Resource.php(41): Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Resources\\IndexViewResource->toArray()
#10 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Controllers/ResourceIndexController.php(19): Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Resources\\Resource->toResponse()
#11 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Controllers\\ResourceIndexController->__invoke()
#12 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction()
#13 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(259): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#14 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(205): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#15 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(806): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#16 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(144): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#17 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/app/Http/Middleware/CheckAuthPermissionsMiddleware.php(32): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#18 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): App\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckAuthPermissionsMiddleware->handle()
#19 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Middleware/Authorize.php(18): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#20 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\Authorize->handle()
#21 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#22 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php(31): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle()
#23 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle()
#24 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Middleware/BootTools.php(20): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#25 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\BootTools->handle()
#26 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Middleware/DispatchServingNovaEvent.php(33): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#27 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\DispatchServingNovaEvent->handle()
#28 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Middleware.php(87): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#29 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Inertia\\Middleware->handle()
#30 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#31 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#32 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#33 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#34 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#35 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#36 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#37 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#38 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#39 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#40 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#41 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#42 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(805): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#43 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(784): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#44 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(748): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#45 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(737): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#46 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#47 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(144): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#48 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Middleware/ServeNova.php(23): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#49 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\ServeNova->handle()
#50 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#51 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#52 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#53 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#54 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#55 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#56 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#57 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#58 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(99): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#59 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#60 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#61 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle()
#62 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#63 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle()
#64 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#65 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#66 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#67 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/public/index.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#68 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/NovaProducts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php(16): require_once('...')
#69 {main}
"}

I left only "ID" field both in fieldsForIndex and fields to reduce possible errors on other fields.
But even if to remove these "ID" fields(empty arrays of fields in boths methods) I got the same error.
I tried to debug this error in vendor/laravel/nova/src/Fields/ID.php :
public static function forModel($model)
{
    \Log::info( ' -100 forModel $model::');
    \Log::info(json_encode($model));        // IT SHOWS NULL
    return tap(static::make('ID', $model->getKeyName()), function ($field) use ($model) {
        $value = $model->getKey();

        if (is_int($value) && $value >= 9007199254740991) {
            $field->asBigInt();
        }

        $field->resolve($model);
    });
}

Method ::forModel( is called from vendor/laravel/nova/src/Resource.php :
protected function serializeWithId(Collection $fields)
{
    \Log::info( ' -01 serializeWithId $fields::');
    \Log::info(json_encode($fields)); // IT SHOWS EMPTY ARRAY IF METHOD `fieldsForIndex` returns empty array

    return [
        'id' => $fields->whereInstanceOf(ID::class)->first() ?: ID::forModel($this->resource),
        'fields' => $fields->all(),
    ];
}

If in method `fieldsForIndex' there are some elements it shows data :
[2024-11-29 14:14:57] local.INFO: [{"attribute":"order_number","component":"text-field","compact":false,"displayedAs":null,"fullWidth":false,"helpText":null,"indexName":"Order number","inline":false,"name":"Order number","nullable":false,"panel":null,"placeholder":null,"prefixComponent":true,"readonly":false,"required":false,"sortable":false,"sortableUriKey":"order_number","stacked":false,"textAlign":"left","uniqueKey":"order_number-default-text-field","usesCustomizedDisplay":false,"validationKey":"order_number","value":null,"visible":true,"withLabel":true,"wrapping":false,"dependentComponentKey":"text.text-field.order_number","dependsOn":null,"dependentShouldEmitChangesEvent":false,"asHtml":false,"copyable":false}]

But the same eeror in any case.
Any idea what is wrong here and how that can be fixed ?
